# Protractor click wrapped p-dropdown - Select value - Element is not clickable at point (x, y) Other element would receive the click

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

i am trying to select my p-calendar element.
This is a dropdown I then want to click on to open it.
After it is opened I want to select (clilck) a value from the list.

But I cannot even click my dropdown element.

Select dropdown element:

```
input = element(by.css('p-dropdown[formcontrolname="currId"]'));
```

This works.
But now when trying to click it:
I receive the following error:

```
</p-dropdown> is not clickable at point (841, 415). Other element would receive the click: <a cla
```

I read I have to select the label:

```
input.$('label').click();
```

But this also doesn't work.

```
</label> is not clickable at point (841, 416). Other element would receive the click: <a class="ui-s
```

My P-dropdown element:

```
<p-dropdown formcontrolname="currId" id="currId" inputid="currId" placeholder="NONE" 
  styleclass="form-control form-control-sm" 
  class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" ng-reflect-filter="true" 
  ng-reflect-style-class="form-control form-control-sm" ng-reflect-placeholder="NONE" 
  ng-reflect-input-id="currId" ng-reflect-options="[object Object],[object Object" 
  ng-reflect-name="currId">
  <div class="ng-tns-c6-1 form-control form-control-sm ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" 
       ng-reflect-klass="form-control form-control-sm" 
       ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" style="width: 96px;">
    <select>
      <option class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" value="AED">AED</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" value="AUD">AUD</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" value="BGN">BGN</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" value="BRL">BRL</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" value="CAD">CAD</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" value="CHF">CHF</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" value="CLP">CLP</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" value="CNY">CNY</option>
      <option class="ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" value="COP">COP</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <input class="ng-tns-c6-1" readonly="" role="listbox" type="text" id="currId" aria-label=" ">
  </div>
  <label class="ng-tns-c6-1 ui-dropdown-label ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-placeholder ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">NONE</label>
  <div class="ui-dropdown-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
    <span class="ui-clickable fa fa-fw fa-caret-down" ng-reflect-klass="ui-clickable" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="ng-tns-c6-1 ui-dropdown-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ng-trigger ng-trigger-panelState" ng-reflect-ng-class="ui-dropdown-panel ui-widget-co" style="display: none; opacity: 0;">
    <div class="ui-dropdown-filter-container ng-tns-c6-1 ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <input class="ui-dropdown-filter ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" type="text">
      <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-dropdown-items-wrapper" style="max-height: 200px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</p-dropdown>
```

How can I select and click this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `a` element is interfering with the click - this can have multiple reason. As a last resort, you can always try to execute some javascript to set its visibility to hidden:

`elem = element(by.css('a.ui-s')` <- enter the rest of the className here

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem actually was some other dropdown window that has been opened before but not closed. This overlayed the whole page and the element I wanted to click.
I just had to close all other open windows before

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is `input = element(by.css('p-dropdown[formcontrolname="currId"]'));` is not clickable as `a class="ui-s` is getting overly over your element.
The best way to resolve this, use `browser.executeScript('');`

**In your case :**
`browser.executeScript('document.querySelector(\'p-dropdown[formcontrolname="currId"]\').click()');`